# Receiving 'KeyError:1 ' , Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a piece of code that returns a user's requested toppings on a pizza.
Here is the code:

```
def topping_menu():
    print("""
    What toppings do you want on your pizza?

        _____________________________________________________
       |   1:Bacon      |  5:Anchovies     |  9:Black Olives |
       |   2:Pepperoni  |  6:Spinach       |  10:Chicken     |
       |   3:Mushrooms  |  7:Onion         |  11:Ground Beef |
       |   4:Pineapple  |  8:Bell Peppers  |  12:Jalapenos   |
       |________________|__________________|_________________| 
       What toppings do you want on your pizza?
       """)
         
def topping_order():

    topping_mappings = {
        1: 'Bacon', 
        2: 'Pepperoni', 
        3: 'Mushrooms', 
        4: 'Pineapple', 
        5: 'Anchovies', 
        6: 'Spinach', 
        7: 'Onions', 
        8: 'Bell Peppers', 
        9: 'Black Olives',
        10: 'Chicken', 
        11: 'Ground Beef',
        12: 'Jalapenos''
        }
    requested_toppings = []

    while True:
        response = input('-')
        toppings_wanted = response
        toppings_wanted = topping_mappings[toppings_wanted]
        requested_toppings.append(requested_toppings)
        

        if response == 'q':
            break

        for requested_topping in requested_toppings:
            if requested_topping in topping_mappings:
                print(f"Adding: {toppings_wanted}")

            else:
                print(f"We do not have {requested_topping}")
    topping_total = len(requested_toppings) * float(1.23)

    print("\nWe are adding the requested toppings to your pizza.")
    print(f"your topping total will be: ${topping_total}")

topping_menu()
topping_order()
```

However when I run the code I get the following error:

```
toppings_wanted = topping_mappings[toppings_wanted]
KeyError: '1'
```

The code should have returned when user enters '1':

```
Adding: Bacon
-q
We are adding the requested toppings to your pizza.
your topping total will be: $1.23
```

My guess is the issue has to do something with 'topping_mappings', or possibly the while loop because this was the last thing I added before I received this error. I have spent some time researching this issue however I have come up with nothing that is helpful.

My question:
Why do I keep getting this issue and how can I fix it so I do not make this error again.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need to convert from string to int.

Comment: Or make the keys of `topping_mappings` strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I edited and added comments where you were wrong.

`def topping_menu():
print("""
What toppings do you want on your pizza?

```
    _____________________________________________________
   |   1:Bacon      |  5:Anchovies     |  9:Black Olives |
   |   2:Pepperoni  |  6:Spinach       |  10:Chicken     |
   |   3:Mushrooms  |  7:Onion         |  11:Ground Beef |
   |   4:Pineapple  |  8:Bell Peppers  |  12:Jalapenos   |
   |________________|__________________|_________________| 
   What toppings do you want on your pizza?
   """)
```

def topping_order():

```
topping_mappings = {
    1: 'Bacon', 
    2: 'Pepperoni', 
    3: 'Mushrooms', 
    4: 'Pineapple', 
    5: 'Anchovies', 
    6: 'Spinach', 
    7: 'Onions', 
    8: 'Bell Peppers', 
    9: 'Black Olives',
    10: 'Chicken', 
    11: 'Ground Beef',
    12: 'Jalapenos'
    }
requested_toppings = []

while True:
    response = input('-')
    if response == 'q':#Checking for Quit
        break
    toppings_wanted = response
    toppings_wanted = topping_mappings[int(toppings_wanted)]#Converting response to int
    requested_toppings.append(toppings_wanted)
    

    

    #for requested_topping in requested_toppings: 
    #You dont need the for loop
    if toppings_wanted in topping_mappings.values():#You were not comparing it with Values
        print(f"Adding: {toppings_wanted}") #This should be toppings wanted

    else:
        print(f"We do not have {toppings_wanted}") #This also should be toppings wanted
topping_total = len(requested_toppings) * float(1.23) #You dont have to write float python knows its float by default

print("\nWe are adding the requested toppings to your pizza.")
print(f"your topping total will be: ${topping_total}")
```

`

Answer (score 1):

- `response = input('-')` the `input` function here will return `str`.
- Your dict `topping_mappings` here has key as `int`. So you need to convert to `int` before this `toppings_wanted = topping_mappings[toppings_wanted]`
- the following change is one way to fix it.

```
response = input('-')
toppings_wanted = int(response) if response.isdigit() else None
toppings_wanted = topping_mappings[toppings_wanted]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. When I made the changes I am now receiving the following error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q' –

Comment: @ChrisJaurigue Check updated answer. You can check if word is digit then convert it otherwise dont.

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong

```
 requested_toppings.append(requested_toppings)
```

it should be

```
 requested_toppings.append(toppings_wanted)
```

and you need to take int as an input

```
response = int(input('-'))
```

and u have an extra '

```
12: 'Jalapenos''
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. When I made the changes I am now receiving the following error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'

Comment: I have posted another answer where I have added comments where you were wrong. Hope comparing both the codes gives you a better understanding. The error that you are asking is because you cant convert an alphabet to int.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is toppings_wanted is a string and your keys are ints

```
toppings_wanted = topping_mappings[int(toppings_wanted)]
```